# codemirror 3.0 format preloaded textarea code

Tags: codemirror

I am using CodeMirror to create an editor in an HTML5 based presentation. In it's simplest form, the html looks something like this.

```
 <section class="pattern">
      <textarea id='pattern-view' class='codemirror' data-mode='javascript'>
           var myModule = function(){
              //code goes here
           }
      </textarea>
 </section>
```

and down in a document ready I have the code

```
 $(function(){
     var tAreas = document.querySelectorAll('.codemirror');
        for (var i = 0; i < tAreas.length; i++) {
           CodeMirror.fromTextArea(tAreas[i], { theme: 'monokai',  mode: tAreas[i].dataset.mode });
        }
 });
```

This works as expected, the textarea is replaced with the editor. The trouble is the indentation is maintained and not properly formatted. It only highlights the code, does not re-format the contents.

Is there something I need to add to this? I did find code for formatting.js addon, which is no longer part of codemirror 3.0.

Is there someway to auto-format the code inside the textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. For those who might chance upon this. Get the formatting.js from the old codemirror and put it where you like. Add this to your dom ready function

```
 var tAreas = document.querySelectorAll('.codemirror'); //assuming all textareas have the class codemirror

        for (var i = 0; i < tAreas.length; i++) {
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(tAreas[i], {theme: 'monokai',mode: tAreas[i].dataset.mode, tabMode: 'indent' });
            CodeMirror.commands["selectAll"](editor);
            autoFormatSelection(editor);
            $(tAreas[i]).trigger({type: 'keypress', which: 13});
        }

        function getSelectedRange(editor) {
            return { from: editor.getCursor(true), to: editor.getCursor(false) };
        }

        function autoFormatSelection(editor) {
            var range = getSelectedRange(editor);
            editor.autoFormatRange(range.from, range.to);
            CodeMirror.commands['goPageUp'](editor);

        }
```

Comment: unfortunately, when I try this approach it actually hardlocks my page, with a constant 25% cpu (the cap per tab process).

Comment: If you have way too many text areas that will be the issue and your screen will lockup. There is no other solution I have come up with or at least I haven't tried anything new. Even if you put this as a long running process and return a promise (or do it in set timeout), you still run the issue of it taking a long time.

Comment: unfortunately, I only had one textarea. Not quite sure why it locked up, but it's pretty terminal, and it did it pretty fast.

Comment: does your textarea have too much code to format? put console.beginTime and console.endTime to see which part of the code is taking longer.

Comment: Hello, i have the same problem.. Could you help me please ?